# javascript for loop syntax and performance

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I study javascript with my book recently purchased. And the book explain about the performance of for loop. That is, there are 2 style,

```
A: for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){ //some code... }

B: for(var i=arr.length-1; i>-1; i--){ //some code... }
```

The book describes "style B is more good performance than A". It seems plausible, but when java(not javascript) syntax I don't care about this situation. So my question is "style B is more effective"? Thank you in advance...

Comment: http://jsperf.com/loops-increment-vs-decrement/5

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry. I'm not good at here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of performance, using the decrement operator `i--` is not necessarily faster than the increment operator `i++`. Performance wise, they are both as fast.

The bottleneck has to do with ascending loops. For every number, the size of the array has to be evaluated. Let's take a look at the two cases.

**Descending Loop**

```
for (var i = array.length; i >= 1; i-- )
```

`array.length` is evaluated only once, upon initialization of the i variable.

**Ascending Loop**

```
for (var i = 1; i <= array.length; i++ )
```

`array.length` is evaluated every time `i` is incremented. You also have to check the value of i to make sure it's less than the length of the array.

For further insights, please look at the following blog post

http://www.2ality.com/2013/07/for-loop-performance.html